# Is a comma necessary before "for which"?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis

Is a comma needed in this sentence?
Is *for which* used correctly in this sentence?

> We define message codes **for which** security is well defined.

Comment: I would say yes, but for the fact that I am not sure if the sentence is grammatical. I am certainly having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comma is either necessary or forbidden, depending on the meaning. For example, here is a context that would require a comma:

> A previous version of this standard used *sender codes*, which offered some protection against unauthenticated messages, but were vulnerable to replay attacks if the same sender could send multiple messages. To address this, we make several improvements in the current version. Most importantly, we define *message codes*, for which security is well defined.

and here is a context that would not permit one:

> It is important to select message codes carefully, since it is all too easy to create message codes whose security cannot be asserted. In this chapter, we define message codes for which security is well defined. We will refer to these throughout the remainder of the book.

The key factor is that the version with the comma implies that "security is well defined" is a property of *all* message codes, whereas the version without the comma implies that "security is well defined" is a property only of *some* message codes.

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictiveness.

Comment: I would add that (well, it is written in wiki. still) without comma, such a property "..." helps to select some entities from all; while, with comma, it is more like a remark.